# Geotag with exiftool failed

Tags: gps, exiftool, nexus-5

After looking at examples in `man exiftool`, it seemed the right command would be

```
exiftool -geotag dir-1/…175814.gpx   -geosync=-3600  dir-2
```

All 36 photos (.jpg) and videos (.mp4) were taken with the same Nexus 5X by me but for reasons I don't understand, exiftool says one of them is from iPhone 6.

It says all the rest are Nexus 5X made by Google except one is also Nexus 5SX but made by Hewlett Packard!

I don't know whether I had GPS turned off or whether it was a defect in the Nexus, but none of that phones photos have GPS tags.

The .gpx file was created by a Garmin device.

All the files were mod `rw-r--r--` and owned by me. The command geotagged three files and for all the rest, said:

> Warning: No writable tags set from /(path)/(filename).jpg

I can't find anything unique about the three files that worked. Two of them are the same as all the others (according to `exiftool -csv`) and one is the "Nexus 5X made by Hewlett Packard."

#### What is the correct command?  Why would the command I used work on three files out of forty-one, all taken the same day by the same device?

**Update:** I get the same number of unchanged files from

```
exiftool -v2 -geotag dir-1/…175814.gpx '-Geotime<${DateTimeOriginal#}-01:00' dir-2
```

but changing the minus to plus changed more files.  Remains to be seen (if I can figure it out) whether the added locations are correct or off by two hours (+1 vs. -1).

**Update 2:** using +2:00:00 instead of minus one got a very accurate position (according to street view) on the image I had checked.  I guess daylight savings time was different then (or there), also that I need to use the time **zone** instead of a time **correction**.

P.S. All the photos were taken by the Nexus I had at the time.  I've never owned or borrowed an iPhone 6 nor a phone or camera from Hewlett-Packard.  And I have never used exiftool or anything else to alter the make/model of any image.  So those wrong tags must have been created by the Nexus.  Unless someone was following me, took two photos near where I had been, and hacked my laptop or Nexus to put them in with the rest!

Comment: Why should the command work for all files? GeoTagging (as I understand it) isn’t universal and some photos/video simply have no location data.

Comment: Maybe you can try `geotag` software: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124416/suggestions-for-an-easy-way-to-add-gps-data-to-jpegs/124419#124419

Comment: @Giacomo1968, geotagging is ADDING the location data by interpolation from the GPX file.

Comment: There are several things I could try.  The question is why exiftool doesn't behave the way the man page _seems_ to say and how to get _exiftool_ to do what was intended.

Comment: Run your command again, but add the `-v2` option.  This will list the start and end times of the geotrack and the geotime exiftool is using for each file.  If the latter doesn't fall between the start and end times, then you need to adjust the `-geosync` offset.  See [Geotag Troubleshooting #3](https://exiftool.org/geotag.html#TR3).

Comment: Well, that shows me something rather disturbing.  I took the pictures in Spain, hence the `geosync=-3600`. Yet a picture that was taken 16:42:23 (UTC 15:42:23) is within the time range of the GPX, but it is not tagged, and the message is: `Geotime value:   2017:09:04 22:42:23.000 UTC (incl. Geosync offset of -3600.000 sec) (local timezone is -06:00)`  Local timezone is completely irrelevant, but 22:42:23 would be using my local Oregon offset and NOT including the geosync value!

Comment: Also, exiftool says `Argument "-Geotime<DateTimeOriginal#" is assumed` but  DateTimeOriginal on that file is 2017:09:04 16:42:23.147884 not 2017:09:04 16:42:23.000

Comment: From the link I gave you "GPS times are in UTC, but the camera times are typically in your local time zone"  Unless you include a time zone, exiftool can only assume local time of the computer.  Remove the `Geosync` option and use `"-Geotime<${DateTimeOriginal#}±00:00"` changing ±00:00 to the local time zone where the image was taken.

Comment: So geosync is the offset from local time and not from GPS time?  That _almost_ fits the correction I saw.  But it doesn't fit the man page statement that `-geosync=+1:20` “compensates for image times which are 1 minute and 20 seconds behind GPS”  (I said "almost" because 22 = 16+6 not 16+6-1)

Comment: I got syntax error messages from that and from several variations.  Finally tried using single-quote instead of double, and that got the same results as originally, i.e., all but three files unchanged.  `-v2` shows the correct UTC now, but it still fails to change all those files, most of which are within the range of the GPX.

Comment: @StarGeek: see my edits.  I suspect you can write a clearer answer than I can.

Comment: The `geosync` option is used to compensate for shifts after the local time in the image was shifted to UTC.  It can be used to adjust from the local time to UTC, but it's better to use `Geotime` with the correct time zone. Lets say I take a picture at 12:00 noon in New York, TZ -04:00.  Then fly to LA to work on the picture.  Because the local TZ is -07:00, exiftool can only assume that the image is 12:00-07:00=19:00 UTC. But the correct time would be 12:00-04:00=16:00 UTC. So the best option would be `"-Geotime<${DateTimeOriginal#}±04:00"`.  But `geosync` could also be used (see next comment)

Comment: As I said, because I'm now in -07:00 TZ, exiftool will use 12:00-07:00= 19:00 UTC by default.  `-Geosync=-3:0:0` could be used to correctly adjust from 19:00 UTC to 16:00 UTC.